# onkeypress vs oninput how to get best of both worlds

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

So I'm using an input and need to get the keycodes so I tried using `onkeypress`. However, I also needed the updated value, which it doesn't actually have when `keypress` event is triggered.

So then I tried using `oninput`, however, while the updated value of an input is there, it doesn't register `keyCode`.

Right now I'm using both events, but was wondering if there was a catch-all event that both contains the `keyCode` and the updated `input`.

```js
$("#test").on('keypress', () => {
  console.log("keypress value: ", event.target.value);
});
$("#test").on('input', () => {
  console.log("input value: ", event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `keyup` event. This will give you both `keycode` and `updatedValue`

```js
$("#test").on('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode, this.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" />
```

When you type a key, following events occurs

1. Key Down: This will register which key is being pressed down. If you want to prevent any key from being typed, this is where you block it.
2. Key Press: This will register which key is being held. Its value is set on keyDown and erased on keyUp.
3. Key Up: This is when you release the key and event chain is completed. This is the event that updates the value.

Answer (score 2):

Another important difference is that,  when you try to upper or lower case, look at this different.

```js
$("#testKeyPress").on('keypress', function () {
  $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});

$("#testInput").on('input', function () {
  $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
KEYPRESS <input id="testKeyPress"/> <br />
INPUT <input id="testInput" />
```

Comment: Nice example, would be better with some explaination.

Comment: Muhammet, this is because the "keypress" event doesn't update the value of the input!
val() doesn't contain what you are typing, yet... The "keyup" event should work though ;-)
In short, "onkeydown/press/up" purpose is to allow precise control over the process of typing and "oninput" just cares about change of the value ;-) I would like to post this as a comment, but I can't :-(